# Display flags in Django form & templates with Django-countries

Tags: django, django-countries

I'm using [Django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) and I don't overcome to display country flags beside each country in my Django Form or in any templates.

I display well the country list, I set correctly the flags folder in my static folder. But impossible to display flags.

In my model I have :

```
PaysNaissance = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
```

Then, my form displays countries like this :

[image]

As you can see, none flags appears in my list. Do you have any idea about this issue ?

Settings are well-configured, and in my template I have :

```
<table style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <p></p>
            <tr>
                <th> Informations sur l'individu </th>
                <th> Données renseignées </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pays de Naissance</td>
                <td>{{personne.PaysNaissance}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

It displays : `FR` 
But If I want to display the flag, I set `{{personne.PaysNaissance.flag}}` and I have `/static/flags/fr.gif`.

So in order to display the flag I have to write :
 `<td><img src='{{personne.PaysNaissance.flag.url}}'/></td>`

But it doesn't seem to work.

In my form part :

```
<form class = "form" method='POST' action='' enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %} <br></br>

        {{ form.as_p }} 
        {{birthday|date:"%d/%m/%Y" }} 
        <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Valider le formulaire ?')" /> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show the exact HTML code of template for the same? The problem is in **<img src=**.

Comment: I added some informations in my question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write :

```
<td><img src='{{personne.PaysNaissance.flag}}'/></td>
```

Because **{{ personne.PaysNaissance.flag }}** itself contains the flag url. You don't need to write flag.url extra.

One more thing can be done :

Use :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'flags/sprite.css' %}">


<td><i class="{{ personne.PaysNaissance.flag_css }}"></i></td>
```

This will work.

Comment: The first step works pretty well ! Just one question : If I want to display flags in my django list form, How I could do that ?

Comment: @Deadpool Can you show me the rendered output of HTML form?? The same way should happen for form also.

Comment: Yes sure, you have an example in my question about my rendering output HTML form. I don't know If I have to add something like this : `{{ form.PaysNaissance.flag}}`

Comment: @Deadpool The {{ form.as_p }} is a model form right?? For that, you need to extend the country name with ints flag also. In the forms.py file.

Comment: You're right ;) Ok I will try some things in my forms.py file ! Thank you

Comment: If I want to extend my django form in order to add flags, I have to add `def __init__` ?

Comment: @Deadpool Not necessarily. You can also set this at the time of Field creation. Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example

Comment: Hum a bit obscur for me but I will try to understand what I have to modify exactly in order to display Country flags ;)